# Animation slide a Button to the top of the screen when The User Clicks a Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-button

I have relative Layout that has Three Buttons, 1 anchored at the top(`TopButton`), One at The Bottom(`BottomButton`, and One that will either be placed directly below the top button or above the bottom button(`MiddleButton`) according to users touching my buttons.

Under Each of these buttons I have placed a ScrollView and then in there a textView. I am trying to make a set of Listeners so that when the User clicks on one of the buttons, the other two buttons ScrollViews (and their textViews) are set to `View.GONE`, and the button that was pushed will have their ScrollView set to `View.Visible`.

In addition to Setting the ScrollViews Visibility I wanted to Change the location of the buttons via a simple sliding animation (all on screen) to one of three set-ups according to the button pushed:

1. **TopButton pushed** - (Opening the Activity, what it is set to now) The scrollView for this button is visible, other two are set to gone, and both buttons are at the bottom of the screen.
2. **MiddleButton pushed** - ScrollView 1 and 3 will be set to gone and ScrollView 2 will be visible, and the `MiddleButton` will slide up just below the `TopButton`. So the order will be `TopButton`, `MiddleButton`, `Scroll/TextView2`, `BottomButton`.
3. **BottomButton pushed** - ScrollViews of 1 and 2 will be set to Gone and 3 will be set to Visible and the `BottomButton` will Slide up to reveal maximum space for the ScrollView. So the order in this one will be `TopButton`, `MiddleButton`, `BottomButton`, `Scroll/TextView3`

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/OverallLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
   tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/TopButton"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/BottomButton"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/MiddleButton"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@id/BottomButton" />

   <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/Scroll1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_above="@id/MiddleButton"
   android:layout_below="@id/TopButton"
   android:visibility="visible" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center" />
   </ScrollView>

   <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/Scroll2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_above="@id/BottomButton"
   android:layout_below="@id/MiddleButton"
   android:visibility="gone" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center" />
    </ScrollView>

   <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/Scroll3"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_below="@id/BottomButton"
   android:visibility="gone" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView3"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center" />
   </ScrollView>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

I need help figuring out the `fromY` and `toY` values for this moving animation to work. What are these set to?

Comment: did you have a specific question?

Comment: How would I do those animations?

I started off with this:
`<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="-1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>`
but it rushes the button to the top and then slowly drags it down to where it started.

Answer (score 0):

here's a translation animation I use. It's called "pull_in_from_top.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromYDelta="-100%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

This one does the opposite "push_out_to_top.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```